# How can I loop through a dataset 100 hundred records at a time? C#

Tags: c#, loops, datatable, dataset

I have a dataset that was roughly 4500 rows. I was passing it to a webservice but after performance issues and timeouts we want to be able to pass 100 of those rows at a time.

How can this be achieved in c#?

Do I need to split the dataset into tables of 100 and then loop through the tables or is there an easier way to send sets of 100 rows at a time?

Comment: How many DataTables are in the DataSet? Is it 4,500 in one DataTable?

Comment: Yes there are 4500 records in the one DataTable I have now.  Right now I am passing that datatable to a webservice all at once.... wanting to pass 100 rows chunks of that DataTable to the webservice

Answer (score 2):

You could use Linq, specifically [Take](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [CopyToDataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx) extension.

Example:

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables["YOURDATATABLE"];
    IEnumerable<DataRow> firstHundred = dt.AsEnumerable().Take(100);
    // create datatable from query
    DataTable boundTable = firstHundred.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
    //call your web service with 1st hundred
    //
    IEnumerable<DataRow> nextHundred = dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(100).Take(100);
    // and so on
    boundTable = nextHundred.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
    //call your web service with 1st hundred
    //
```

Example with simple for and Linq which takes into account you have 4,500 rows and want to chunk it by groups of 100:

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables["YOURDATATABLE"];
    IEnumerable<DataRow> firstHundred = dt.AsEnumerable().Take(100);
    // create datatable from query
    DataTable boundTable = firstHundred.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
    //call your web service with 1st hundred
    //

    int skipCount = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 45; i++)
    {
        skipCount += 100;
        IEnumerable<DataRow> nextHundred = dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(skipCount).Take(100);
        // create datatable from query
        DataTable boundTable = nextHundred.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
        // call web service with next hundred and so on
    }
```

Comment: So basically you iterate the datarows over and over and over when getting chunks, certainly a non-linq solution would be a better approach in this scenario.

Comment: If you are referring to performance, then yes - LINQ can be a bit slower. But for 4,500 rows - I seriously doubt it matters. I proposed LINQ in this case because I think its shorter, more readable, and more maintainable code vs. some complex looping code.

Answer (score 1):

```
private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<DataRow>> GetChunks(DataTable table, int size)
{
    List<DataRow> chunk = new List<DataRow>(size);

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        chunk.Add(row);
        if (chunk.Count == size)
        {
            yield return chunk;
            chunk = new List<DataRow>(size);
        }
    }

    if(chunk.Any()) yield return chunk;
}

//....

DataTable table = dataSet.Tables[yourTable];
var chunks = GetChunks(table, 100);

foreach (IEnumerable<DataRow> chunk in chunks)
    SendChunk(chunk); // <-- Send your chunk of DataRow to webservice
```

You can also attempt to send the data on parallel:

```
// This would replace the above last two lines
Parallel.ForEach(chunks, chunk => SendChunk(chunk));
```

Although I'd not recomment that, since `SendChunk` is an I/O operation.

Instead, try to convert your code to `async`, and you can get better results:

```
// Will execute all tasks at the same time
// SendChunk should return a Task
await Task.WhenAll(chunks.Select(chunk => SendChunk(chunk)).ToArray());
```

Comment: why does it not recognize chunk.add or chunk.any?

Comment: @JoeStarnes Try adding `using System.Linq` at the top of your source code. Also, note that methods are in pascal case notation, i.e. `Add` and `Any`

Comment: i'm somewhat new to C# so help me understand this. Is going to take my original dataset named (LPsToCleanup) of 4,500 rows and call GetChunks(LPsToCleanup, 100)? Is that going to break that into new datasets of size 100 rows?

Comment: @JoeStarnes `GetChunks` doesn't take a `DataSet` as an argument, you'll have to pass in your `DataTable` -> `GetChunks(myDataTable, 100)`. It won't give you a new `DataTable` of size 100, instead it'll give you a list of "chunks" of `DataRow` instances.

Comment: hmm ok before I was passing my datatable to a helper.... what datatype is 'chunk' because it doesn't seem to like that when i try to pass it.

Comment: @JoeStarnes A "chunk" is an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, you'll have to update your `SendChunk` method's signature accordingly. If your method expects a `List<DataRow>`, you can even pass in `chunk.ToList()` and avoid changing the signature.

Comment: ok i will try that... but it still doesn't like chunk.Add(row). 'has some invalid arguments'

Comment: @JoeStarnes Try `chunk.Add((DataRow)row)` instead